# Minimum screen size in android for fragments to be seen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I m trying to run the code given here - http://code.google.com/p/android-honeycomb-fragment-tutorial/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed on a 7 inch emulator in portrait or landscape using the android support package. Well from the code its obvious portrait shouldn't show up the fragments but neither is landscape.
But no matter what I do I am not able to see the fragments in the screen. Is there a minimum screen setting for seeing the different fragment screens in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no minimum screen setting for fragments to be show on Android.
You see only one fragment because they have a single fragment in both the activities in the Portrait mode.

Portrait : http://code.google.com/p/android-honeycomb-fragment-tutorial/source/browse/trunk/res/layout/main.xml

In the Lanscape mode there are two fragments shown, and these should show up

Landscape : http://code.google.com/p/android-honeycomb-fragment-tutorial/source/browse/trunk/res/layout-land/main.xml

Comment: I get the portrait thing which is obvious like I mentioned. But when I turn the tablet into Landscape mode (both emulator and a real 7 inch tablet) it does not show the two fragments. Any idea why ?

Comment: Got it - i had somehow stupidly deleted the layout-land.Thanks!

Comment: But I have a question - how does it detect that the layout is separated for landscape and portrait ?

Comment: folder layout-land with the same layout file means there is a separate layout for portrait and lanscape